# Get score for specific fields of documents

Tags: mongodb, search

I have this collection in mongoDB:-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ba281e60bf38bc0e53d592"),
"name" : "abc",
"POST" : [
    {
        "TITLE" : "Dog eats cat",
        "BODY" : "Dog is cat's enemy"
    },
    {
        "TITLE" : "Dog is close to humans",
        "BODY" : "Dog is the best friend man can have"
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ba28b960bf38bc0e53d593"),
"name" : "abc",
"POST" : [
    {
        "TITLE" : "Men are from mars",
        "BODY" : "NASA found rats on mars and venus."
    },
    {
        "TITLE" : "Big cat found",
        "BODY" : "Cat can be friendly if it is small."
    }
]
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ba2a0c60bf38bc0e53d594"),
"name" : "abc",
"POST" : [
    {
        "TITLE" : "Cat eats rats",
        "BODY" : "Rat found dead on mars."
    },
    {
        "TITLE" : "Humans and rats are genetically close",
        "BODY" : "Humans test their new medicines on rats"
    }
]
}
```

I created a Index on `POST.TITLE` and `POST.BODY` using 
`db.a.createIndex({"POST.TITLE":"text","POST.BODY":"text"})`

When I search the collection `a` using the query:-

`db.a.find({$text:{$search:"rat"}},{score: {$meta:"textScore"}})`

gives me this:-

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ba28b960bf38bc0e53d593"),
"name" : "abc",
"POST" : [
    {
        "TITLE" : "Men are from mars",
        "BODY" : "NASA found rats on mars and venus."
    },
    {
        "TITLE" : "Big cat found",
        "BODY" : "Cat can be friendly if it is small."
    }
],
"score" : 0.6
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56ba2a0c60bf38bc0e53d594"),
"name" : "abc",
"POST" : [
    {
        "TITLE" : "Cat eats rats",
        "BODY" : "Rat found dead on mars."
    },
    {
        "TITLE" : "Humans and rats are genetically close",
        "BODY" : "Humans test their new medicines on rats"
    }
],
"score" : 2.5166666666666666
}
```

It gives me `score` for each document. But I want to get this `score` field-wise. By this I mean that when I search for anything(e.g. rat) I want to get score for each TITLE and BODY separately and not of the entire document. Tried many ways but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the text searching capability is that the score is at the document level.  Since you are searching against two fields that are indexed that score is really a composite score from searching the two fields. I don't think there is a way to get a score per field. I looked at the mongo docs again in case something has changed but it also says that the "score" is per document.

In looking at your model it looks like you have two blog documents and in each blog document there are multiple blog posts.  If you are trying to find specific blog posts that score high on your search you might consider modeling this differently where you have a blog posts collection that you can search against which would give you a score per blog post.

Comment: I too saw it in the docs. It formally states that the score is for dcument. So, is their no way at all to get this working. Doesn't matter if its complex. Can't i try `foreach()` loop with `$meta` to get score for per field.

Comment: No, per the doc the score is at the document level... not the field level.  Per my answer you would need to model this differently to achieve a score per post/title combo.